# Insert Account Record by REST API and Postman

Tags: integration

I am new to the Sales Force and i wanted to do one POC to insert one Account record by using REST api and POSTMAN tool.

Please help me out to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? You can start with installing postman and reading https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm quick start and examples section

Comment: If you are new to salesforce i stro gly recommend you start doing trailheads! Its a great way to get started with the platform.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to create a connected App in Salesforce to Login into Salesforce via POSTMAN. You can follow these blog posts to create one.

https://blog.mkorman.uk/using-postman-to-explore-salesforce-restful-web-services/
http://www.mstsolutions.com/blog/content/testing-salesforce-web-service-using-postman-rest-client

Regarding inserting an Account in Salesforce, you have to POST a JSON request like this

```
{
  "Name" : "Express Logistics and Transport"
}
```

To your org's endpoint URL

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/Account/
```

via POSTMAN. I would recommend you to go through the [Force.com REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm) to learn more.